# What do the colors say?

Tags: pattern, visual

This color box contains a sentence. Figure out what it is:

[image]

**Hint:**

> Each row is a single word of the sentence.

Comment: Is it something to do with the image title being WWFMe?

Comment: @Michal, oh no buddy... that's a random generated name from http://i.stack.imgur.com/

Comment: If you download the image the filename is WWFme.png

Comment: I thing there is a clue already black is E?

Comment: I think it's a fantastic idea for a puzzle, but I'm stumped for where to begin :-) Still thinking on it

Comment: @Michal Yes, when you upload an image with Stack Exchange's imgur service it gives it a random name (i.e. http://i.stack.imgur.com/abcdef.png).

Comment: "enter image description here", because it is the name included in <img> HTML tag

(Yes, I know it is not the correct answer) :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may be off on the second word here. My answer is

> What is your color

If this is correct, I will edit and post the explanation.

Edit: Here's the explanation.

> You spell out the names of the colors. So the first row becomes:
>  `White White Black White Blue`
>  
>  Then pick the letters from each of the word that lies in the same
>  position as the color in the row. So, you will pick the following
>  letters as highlighted in Bold:
>
>  **W**hite W**h**ite Bl**a**ck Whi**t**e Blue**blank space**
>  
>  So, the first row gives you **What**
>  
>  Similarly analyzing the rest of the rows and always assuming blue to
>  be blank space, you get
>  
>  **S**ilver P**i**nk Blue Blue Blue = Si = re-ordering = **is**
>  
>  **O**range P**u**rple Pu**r**ple Gra**y** Blue = Oury = re-ordering = **your**
>  
>  **O**range O**r**ange Ye**l**low Bla**c**k Yell**o**w = Orlco = re-ordering = **color**
>  
>  Hence the sentence becomes **What is your color**

Comment: How the if you see cay do you come up with this crazy she hit its teeth stuff! Seriously though, it feels like you and the author of the post are working in coercion.

Answer (score 9):

I hope it is OK to post the same answer as Hetal:

> "what is your color" based on the following steps:
>
>  1. Spell each color in each box
>  .... white white black white blue
>  .... silver pink blue blue blue
>  .... orange purple purple gray blue
>  .... orange orange yellow black yellow
>
>  2. Select nth letter from each word where n is the column number, except that blue is always a blank
>  .... w h a t _
>  .... s i _ _ _
>  .... o u r y _
>  .... o r l c o
>
>  3. Unscramble each row

Comment: What is your color?....;)